# Specific location of intersection between Sphere and 3D Line Segment

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry

I know the question of if the intersection occurs has been answered, but I've been unable to find where.

The breakdown I have is as follows.

```
Circle (alpha, beta, gamma) with radius r
Points at (a,b,c) and (d,e,f)

m = (e-b)/(d-a) slope of xy
n = (f-c)/(d-a) slope of xz

y = m(x-a) + b
z = m(x-a) + c

Combine equation of sphere and line

(x-alpha)^2 + (m(x-a) + b - beta)^2 + (n(x-a) + c - gamma)^2 = r^2

after algebra

(1+m^2+n^2)x^2 + (-2*alpha + 2*m*(-m*a + b - beta) + 2*n*(-n*a + c - gamma))x + (alpha^2 + (-m*a + b - beta)^2 + (-n*a + c - gamma)^2 - r^2) = 0
```

I then tried using the above in the quadratic formula, but using a circle at `2,3,1` with radius `2` and a line from `0,0,0` to `4,4,4` I got x values of `25.35` and `10.65`which don't seem right.

Any help with figuring out what I may have done wrong here would be appreciated.

Comment: Sphere or circle ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, the center of the sphere is the origin (if not, subtract the center coordinates from all points).

The implicit equation of the sphere is

```
X² + Y² + Z² = R².
```

The parametric equation of the line segment:

```
X = X0 + t X01, Y = Y0 + t Y01, Z = Z0 + t Z01.
```

Plugging the second equation into the first,

```
(X01² + Y01² + Z01²) t² + 2 (X01.X0 + Y01.Y0 + Z01.Z0) t + X0² + Y0² + Z0² - R² = 0
```

This is a standard quadratic equation that you solve for `t`.

The two roots define an interval inside the sphere, that it suffices to intersect with `[0, 1]` to know the useful portion of the line segment.

Comment: This is essentially the solution, after some googling I did uncover the right answer. Part of the issue was some finicky parens in Python, because I never write the quadratic formula correctly the first time.

Comment: Isn't this sphere-line intersection?

Comment: @Benjamin: this is said in the answer.

Comment: okay the thing that led to the confusion is that this is "sphere line intersection" and not "sphere line-segment intersection" i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for distance to sphere or ball? Sphere is surface of ball. In sphere case if whole segment is inside sphere than, distance is larger than 0.

It is enough to calculate distances of end points (D1, D2) to sphere center (C) and find point on line (not segment) that is closest to sphere center (X). With that:

In ball case:

```
if X is on segment:
  return max(0, dist(X,C)-R)
return max(0, min(D1, D2)-R)
```

In sphere case:

```
if X is on segment:
  if dist(X,C) < R:        # Nearest point is inside sphere
    if max(D1, D2) >= R:   # One of points is out
      return 0             # Than segment intersects sphere
    return R - max(D1, D2) # Whole segment is inside sphere, end point is nearest (because of ball convexity)
  return R - dist(X,C)     # Whole segment is out
if D1 < R and D2 < R:      # Whole segment is in
  return R - max(D1, D2)
if D1 >= R and D2 >= R:    # Whole segment is out
  return R - min(D1, D2)
return 0                   # Segment intersects sphere
```